# 2 Round Corners of a UIView in UITableViewCell not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rounded-corners

I am trying to create round corners for a UIView with in a custom TableViewCell. The problem is when the table view loads, it only rounds the Top Left corner of the view and not the bottom one. Now when i scroll the table view little bit, it rounds the bottom left part of the view as well.

I have tried every possible method but i can't get my head around it. I am also attaching the screenshots as well as copying the code. Thanks

[image: Table Cell Image]

The code that i am using in the custom view cell class is below.

```
class FoodTVCell: UITableViewCell {

var food: Food!

@IBOutlet weak var foodPicture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var foodName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodRating: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var deliveryTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var minOrder: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var category: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPriceLabelBG: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPrice: UILabel!


   override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    foodPicture.layer.cornerRadius = 75/2
    foodPicture.clipsToBounds = true

}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let corners = UIRectCorner.TopLeft.union(UIRectCorner.BottomLeft)
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: foodPriceLabelBG.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)).CGPath
    foodPriceLabelBG.layer.mask = maskLayer
    foodPriceLabelBG.clipsToBounds = true
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *'corner rounding'* code is working very well, the problem is that your `UIView`'s bottom edge is going outside of your `Cell`'s bottom edge. Decrease your `UIView`'s `Y` position and it will be covered by your `Cell`. I see your cell's separator line invisible too, that means you should give larger height to your Cell at `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

You said it's working very well on scrolling, I suppose it's working when scrolling down and not working when scrolling to top. It means that your first cell was redrawn after second while scrolling to the bottom (where the second cell doesn't cover your first cell), and vice versa while scrolling to the top (where second cell covers your first cell)

Comment: Thanks for your Comment. Actually it was a height issue of the cell. I just increase it from 130 to 132 and it worked like a charm. My bad i couldn't think of that before coming here :)

Also the UIView was not out of Cell's bottom edge in the story board. For the "cell's separator line", it is actually visible but i took a screenshot so it is not visible.

What i meant by scrolling is that if i even moved it 1px, the cell was redrawn and bottom corner showed OK. Anyways thanks for pointing out the issue.