# Where to set UIRectCorner inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I want to apply some round corners to the bottom and top left of a view inside a table cell. And I made this extension on `UIView`:

```
extension UIView {
    func round(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

But I am not sure where exactly to call this on my view to display it correctly. Right now I have it called in `layoutSubviews()` of my custom cell, but the bottom left part is not round when I start my app, only after the cell goes out of the screen and gets redrawn.

What should be a good place to set the round corners inside a `UITableViewCell` ?

edit:

Here is the screenshot with the hierarchy:
[image]

Code:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    configureView()
}

func configureView() {
    bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    period.round([.bottomLeft, .topLeft], radius: 3.0)
    bgView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    period.layer.masksToBounds = false
    bgView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
    bgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    bgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
}
```

edit 2:

[image]

Comment: I would simply set the cornerRadius of the layer itself, rather than using a CAShapeLayer.

Comment: How would I select the corners which I want to be round ?

Comment: Ah, Ok, I assumed you wanted all corners to be round.

Comment: The following question might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241103/2-round-corners-of-a-uiview-in-uitableviewcell-not-working?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too, I tried increasing it, but still nothing changes.

Comment: @Kobe What are you modifying? Is it a table cell's content view or is it some UIView placed inside a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Its a view inside another view which is inside the UITableViewCell. The parent view has also have cornerRadius set

Comment: Can you show your view hierarchy and the result you are getting? Also the code where are you writing to make them round?

Comment: Ok, I updated my question with code and screenshot.

Comment: @Kobe Check the answer and you can use your round method accordingly in any view which you want to make round. I tried with cell's content view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my `CustomTableViewCell` class

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var period: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

        // you might not be doing this earlier
        bgView.clipsToBounds = true

        period.round([.bottomLeft,.topLeft], radius: 5.0)

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

My TableView datasource methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

[image]

My view hierarchy

[image]

Comment: Ok, my cell has a background view and this one has all round corners, and then this background view, has a view on the left side which hides my left round corners for background view, that is why for that view I want only the left part (top and bottom) to have round corners too.

Comment: @Kobe Can you share the final output what you want exactly, also remember the `clipSubviews` property when there are multiple parent child views

Comment: I added a new screenshot where u can see that the bottom part is not updated to have round corners only top part. This changes after I scroll down and cell goes out of the screen, then it will have both corners round.